# Bounds on the derivative of a weakly monotonic function?

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity

I am studying a function $f : R \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $f'(x) \geq 0$.

Do the bounds on the function plus weak monotonicity imply $f'(x) \leq 1$?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be *weak monotone*?

Comment: Consider the sigmoid function $t\mapsto1/(1+e^{-ct})$. You can make
this function's derivative as large as you desire by taking $c>0$ large
enough (having said that, we still don't know what weakly monotone
is, so this might not be the counterexample you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

No way.

Actually, for any $k>0$, you can build $C^\infty$ function which bijectively maps $\mathbb{R}$ onto $]0,1[$ and has $f^\prime (0)>k$.

For example, take $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let:
$$ f_n(x) := \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan (n x) \; ;$$
straightforward computations show that:
$$f_n^\prime (x) = \frac{n}{\pi(1+n^2x^2)}\; ,$$
hence $f_n^\prime (0)>k$ when you choose $n>\pi k$.

Therefore it suffices to take $f_4(x)$ in order to provide a counterexample to your guess. ;-)

Comment: Ha - yes. Thanks for this!